# How can I use Azure ADB2C to implement mobile app AuthN/AuthZ?

Tags: android, azure-ad-b2c

The current Azure ADB2C Mobile app example here that forcibly opens a browser component outside the app and after Sign-In redirects back to the app.

Is there any way to skip this ugly and clunky Sign-In page altogether and do Sign-In/Sign-up directly from a mobile app component? I want to create my own Sign-In `Activity` so I only go to the portal to get the token through a REST `uri` and never have to open a browser outside my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can create [a resource owner policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc) that enables you to gather a user credential in your mobile app and then validate it in your Azure AD B2C tenant.

You can use a client library, such as [AppAuth for Android](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android) or [AppAuth for iOS](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS), to manage the policy invocation for you.

Comment: https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications Apparently, using a resource owner policy just to get around a login page is a very bad idea.

Comment: Correct. It isn't recommended. But it is supported.

Comment: So, is there no other way to use an in-app login page?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but the question still resonated with me a year later. There is an answer to this:

```
.WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true)
```

The full snippet (taken and adapted from an Azure GitHub sample) is:

```
async void OnLoginButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AuthenticationResult result;
        try
        {
            //bool useEmbeddedWebView = !App.IsSystemWebViewAvailable;
            result = await App.AuthenticationClient
                .AcquireTokenInteractive(Constants.Scopes)
                .WithPrompt(Prompt.SelectAccount)
                .WithParentActivityOrWindow(App.UIParent)
                .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(true)
                .ExecuteAsync();

            await Navigation.PushAsync(new LogoutPage(result));
        }
        catch (MsalException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message != null && ex.Message.Contains("AADB2C90118"))
            {
                result = await OnForgotPassword();
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new LogoutPage(result));
            }
            else if (ex.ErrorCode != "authentication_canceled")
            {
                await DisplayAlert("An error has occurred", "Exception message: " + ex.Message, "Dismiss");
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that this isn't a complete working solution, but it does force the B2C template to load into a WebView rather than opening a browser and revealing your domain name. Put it in the shared code project.

You don't get to use your own login page, but it does at least appear to be part of your app.

Reference: [Xamarin Considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-xamarin-android-considerations)

Hopefully Microsoft will address this failing in future releases.